# declare two properties with different type but with similar name in C#

Tags: c#, properties

can i declare two properties with different type but with similar name in C#.
Something like this:

```
public class Types
{
    public string Element
        {
            get { return ""; }
        }
    public int Element
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't do that. Why didn't you just try it yourself?!

Comment: What does the compiler tell you? Those names aren't similar, they're identical

Comment: Have you tried to actually compile your code. You will get your answer faster than asking a question on SO...

Comment: Please get your terminology right, judging by your example you mean `With the same name` not `With similar name`.

Comment: may suggest how to do something like that?

Comment: @user2185915: You just can't. What are you trying to *achieve* here?

Comment: @MykhailoVashchuk You can't do this. See Jon Skeet's answer. `object x` would have to hold `""` or `0`, but which one? Also, instead of asking "can I do this?", you should try it out for yourself, then ask "I tried this, but it didn't work. How can I do something like that?"

Answer (score 5):

*Similar* name? Yes. The *same* name? No.

The only times you can have two members with the same name declared in the same class are with constructors and methods - and those have to have different signatures for each overload.

From the C# 4 spec, section 10.3:

> The names of constants, fields, properties, events, or types must differ from the names of all other members declared in the same class.

If this *were* allowed, it would be extremely confusing and lead to obviously ambiguous code:

```
Types types = new Types();
object x = types.Element; // What would this do?
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to run the code which you wrote and get the error but you may want something similar to below

```
  public class Types<T>
    {
        public T Element
        {
            get { return default(T); }
        }

    }
```